# This browser doesn't support inline PDFs, on chrome on mobile phones

Tags: html, pdf, frontend, cross-browser, backend

We, a corporate gifting company, need to publish the impact report as a PDF file embedded in the webpage. The issue is that when I open the page in the mobile with Chrome browser, it says this browser doesn't support inline PDF. I need it to work not only on Chrome but nearly on all browsers on the mobile. Below is the HTML. Could you please educate me on how I go about ensuring mobile users can view the PDF right in the page instead of first having to download and then view it separately.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
}

/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* Sticky navbar - toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed). The sticky value is not supported in IE or Edge 15 and earlier versions. However, for these versions the navbar will inherit default position */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Right-aligned link */
.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Active/current link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.pdfobject-container { 
  width: 840px;   
  height: 500px;   
  margin: auto; 
}

.pdfobject { border: 1px solid #666; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>My Website</h1>
  <p>A <b>responsive</b> website created by me.</p>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="right">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
    <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
</div>

<div id="example1"> 
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfobject/2.2.7/pdfobject.js"></script>
<script>PDFObject.embed("MiiR_Impact_Report_2020.pdf", "#example1");</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please make it cleared to me? I'm not sure if you are suggesting a solution

Comment: This was fixed long time ago, thanks for looking